# How to declare, same webelement with different ids using Findby?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

For instance, is it possible to define:

`@FindBy(By.id("id1")` OR `By.id("form1:id1"))`
public WebElement button

So that button having either "id1" or "form1:id1" should work fine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @FindBys annotation, the syntax is:

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(id = "foo"),
           @FindBy(className = "bar")})
```

The JavaDoc describes it here:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBys.html

Answer (score 0):

Well,
use whathever you want, *as long as it works*

Personally I would use `@FindBy(By.id("id1"))` but it is just point of choice.

Also, there is no value added in referring same element twice with two different methods. It will only cause mess in your code

**EDIT**
As I understood your comment, there is element on the page which constantly changes its ID. If you need to refer to such elements, try using **xPath** See for example this [xpath tutorial](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example1.html)

The idea is that you will point to some place in the DOM rather than to specific ID

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
Not sure you understood my questions, 
I need to declare same object which shows "id1" first time "id2" next time (both id1 & id2 are static),
my questions was is it possible to declare something like,

@FindBy(By.id("id1")||By.id("id2")) So that the same webelement works for both .

Comment: yep, if the id is dynamic, it's better to get the element with cssSelector or xpath.

Comment: It depends on the form of the ids (how dynamic they are). If they're quite unique just with random numeric suffix, using cssSelector/xpath is the way to do. If they are like ExtJs' auto-generated ids, then you need something else like identifiable class names.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath or CSS selector to do that. Or Java to store the ID name in String and then you can fill it to your Id.